# What is the mechanism to solve a deadlock for the election of the US House Speaker?

Tags: united-states, congress

If there ends up being more than 2 candidates for Speakership and no candidate receiving majority in the ballot, are there mechanism to solve the deadlock?

For example, one might force a runoff between 2 best candidates or eliminae the lowest-scoring candidate for the next round until someone get a majority.

Answer (score 7):

An [1860 New York Times article on the subject](http://www.nytimes.com/1860/01/10/news/the-election-of-speaker.html), which seems surprisingly relevant today, notes multiple occasions (specifically, in 1849 and 1855-56) on which, after several ballots where no candidate reached a majority, the standard was changed to a plurality of votes cast in the presence of a quorum.

A [more recent Vox article](http://www.vox.com/2015/1/6/7495729/house-speaker-election-boehner) indicates there hasn't been much in the way of updates since then.  Votes can take months and this history is the precedent we have for resolving a deadlock.

In 1940, when a Speaker died during session, the House elected a new one by passage of a resolution.

See also: 
[Deschler's Precedents](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-HPREC-DESCHLERS-V1/html/GPO-HPREC-DESCHLERS-V1-1-2-6.htm), Volume 1, Chapter 1 (Assembly of Congress), A (Meeting and Organization), § 6 (Election of the Speaker), available from the U.S. Government Printing Office [here](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-HPREC-DESCHLERS-V1/html/GPO-HPREC-DESCHLERS-V1-1-2-6.htm).

---

At the time period most relevant to this question and answer, the "mechanism to solve a deadlock" is that [John Boehner will stay on](http://www.wsj.com/articles/house-speaker-john-boehner-to-stay-until-replacement-found-1444383000) until somebody else is identified who would win a majority of votes for the speakership.