# What is the seating capacity of the U. S. House of Representatives gallery?

Tags: united-states, congress, house-of-representatives

How many can sit in the House of Representatives gallery?

What are the maximum allowed seatings for the USHR gallery during:

1. A [joint session of Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_session_of_the_United_States_Congress).
2. A [State of the Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_the_Union) address.
3. A public Presidential address.

Comment: Which Senate? Adding some country tags might, might help this question. Otherwise, have you tried google?

Comment: Given the timing, *could* be US, even if 2017 being first post-election year there's no "state of the union" address.

Comment: @Brythan, is the revised Q still unclear?

Comment: Though it's a government building...this doesn't really seem like a political question. More of a facilities management question.

Comment: Related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9239/how-many-seats-are-physically-on-house-floor.  Doesn't address the number in the *gallery*, though.

Answer (score 1):

> How many can sit in the House of Representatives gallery?

User FatBabyGiraffe on Reddit r/ask_politics provided an answer on Feb 05 2019.

> [How many people can the house of representatives chamber hold?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ask_Politics/comments/anad44/how_many_people_can_the_house_of_representatives/)
>
> > There are about 450 seats on the House floor with room for more chairs to be brought in. Gallery seating is about another 500.